# How to fix Fatal error require, problem with include_path

Tags: php

I'm publishing my website but when I try to test it always brings back a mistake.

The fatal error occurred is:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'mywebsite.it/builtit/includes/mysql.inc.php' (include_path='.:') in /membri/testinsit/builtit/index.php on line 3

I've tried to change the path several times, I've searched for solutions here on SO but nothing has helped me.

These are the constants that I use in the config.inc.php file.

```
define('BASE_URI', 'mywebsite.it/builtit');
define('BASE_URL', 'mywebsite.it/builtit');
define('MYSQL', 'mywebsite.it/builtit/includes/mysql.inc.php');
```

This is the code in the `index.php` file that requires the config file and the MYSQL constant.

```
require('./includes/config.inc.php');
require(MYSQL);
```

I've tried also to change the path `(./includes/config.inc.php)` to `(includes/config.inc.php)`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't include files from a webserver with a url. It includes local files.

Define your paths as such:

```
define('MYSQL', './includes/mysql.inc.php');
```

Comment: @Ivan if it worked, please upvote and accept the solution